# Extending a return object with keys matching a dynamic child

Tags: typescript, types

I'd like to have a function that take an object with an optional key (`inst`) which will then use the keys of the `inst` object to create a return object - for example:

```
function init( db, config ) {
    let ret = {};

    if ( config.inst ) {
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(config.inst)) {
            ret[ key ] = value+1; // would normally do some kind of processing here
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

If that were called with `init( db, { inst: { a: 1, b: 2 } } );` it would return `{ a: 2, b: 3 }`. Yes its a bit redundant, but its as much as I could simplify what I'm thinking of!

While its easy enough to code this up in Javascript, I cannot for the life of me figure out an interface that I should define for this function to let TypeScript handle the returned data and types.

The key bit that is tripping me up is how to get the keys of the `inst` nested object. I know I can get the keys of an object using `keyof` or `in`, but I can't see how to apply it here.

Any help very welcome indeed!

**Follow up** - Changing type of the returned properties

As a follow up, this answer assumes that the type of the returned parameters will match what was passed in for `inst`. What if the type is changed? For example changing numbers to being a string, or vice-versa?

```
type Config<T extends {}> = {
    inst?: T
}

function init<T extends {}>(db, config: Config<T>): T & {} {
    let ret: any = {};

    if ( config.inst ) {
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(config.inst)) {
            if ( typeof value === 'number' ) {
                ret[ key ] = value.toString();
            }
            else {
                ret[ key ] = parseInt( value, 10 );
            }
        }
    }

    return ret;
}


let { num, str } = init( null, { inst: { num: '1', str: 2 } } );
```

With this, the destructed `num` will be a string, while `str` will be a number, which is incorrect per the "processing" that the function does. Is there a way to have TypeScript infer the correct type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, something like this should represent what you are doing, so you don't actually need to do anything with the keys to propagate the type info correctly:

```
type Config<T extends {}> = {
    inst?: T
}

function init<T extends {}>(db, config: Config<T>): T | {} {
    let ret = {};

    if ( config.inst ) {
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(config.inst)) {
            ret[ key ] = value+1; // would normally do some kind of processing here
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

You should probably return something else than an empty object (e.g. undefined) for the false case though, so that it's easier to check afterwards in a way that TypeScript understands, which of the cases happened.

Comment: That's _brilliant_ thank you. I was totally barking up the wrong tree it seems. I had to make one small change - the return type was an intersection rather than a union. I've edited my original post to add a follow up question, if that is okay, I'm wondering specifically what to do when the "processing" changes the type of the data to return.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the types of the members you will need to add some mapped and conditional types to your return type (see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) for docs on them). You will need to express the processing you perform in terms of conditional types (in effect duplicating the processing algorithm in terms of types) but at least the caller will get apropriate types:

```
type Config<T extends {}> = {
    inst?: T
}

function init<T extends {}>(db, config: Config<T>): {
  [P in keyof T]: // take each property of T
    T[P] extends number ? string : number // If the property T[P] is a number the new property type will be string otherwise it will be number
} {
    let ret: any = {};

    if ( config.inst ) {
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(config.inst)) {
            if ( typeof value === 'number' ) {
                ret[ key ] = value.toString();
            }
            else {
                ret[ key ] = parseInt( value, 10 );
            }
        }
    }

    return ret;
}


let { num, str } = init( null, { inst: { num: '1', str: 2 } } );
```