# Infering return type in a nested object with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

This is [largely a follow up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53091779/extending-a-return-object-with-keys-matching-a-dynamic-child) of a previous question on a similar topic, but it was simplified a bit.

Essentially what I am trying to do is pass an object's parameters and values through a converter function (it will be a factory builder, but I've simplified it here to change numbers into strings and vice versa) then assign those properties to the object returned and retain typing.

This is the code I've been experimenting with:

```
type Config<T extends {[key:string]: number | string}> = {
    inst?: T
}

function convert ( value: string ): number;
function convert ( value: number ): string
function convert( value: any ): any {
    if ( typeof value === 'number' ) {
        return value.toString();
    }

    return parseInt( value.toString(), 10 );
}

function init<T extends {[key:string]: any}>(db, config: Config<T>): T & {} {
    let ret: any = {};

    if ( config.inst ) {
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(config.inst)) {
            let res = convert( value );
            ret[ key ] = res;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}


let a = convert( '1' ); // `a` is a `number`
let b = convert( 2 );   // `b` is a `string`

let { strToNum, numToStr } = init( null, { inst: { strToNum: '1', numToStr: 2 } } );
// `strToNum` is a string - should be a number
// `numToStr` is a number - should be a string
```

The convert function appears to work okay with the overload type, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the type to apply to the returned object's parameters. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want to combine [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) (to represent switching `string` to `number` and vice-versa) with [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) (to represent this switch on every property):

```
type Convert<T extends string | number> = T extends number ? string : number;
declare function init<T extends { [key: string]: any }>(
  db: any, 
  config: Config<T>
): {[K in keyof T]: Convert<T[K]>};
```

And try it:

```
let { strToNum, numToStr } = init(null, { inst: { strToNum: '1', numToStr: 2 } });
strToNum.toFixed(0);  // okay
numToStr.charAt(0); // okay
```

Looks good.

---

As an aside, you could also use that conditional type to represent your `convert()` function, which might be preferable to multiple overloads for some purposes:

```
function convert<T extends string | number>(value: T): Convert<T>;
function convert(value: string | number): string | number {
  if (typeof value === 'number') {
    return value.toString();
  }
  return parseInt(value.toString(), 10);
}

convert(Math.random()<0.5 ? "1" : 2); // string | number
// the above will fail with overloads
```

---

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: That's brilliant - thank you! I've [posted a follow up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189169/resolve-a-promise-in-a-typescript-type) based on this, attempting to switch from `string` and `number` types to a class. If you might be willing to take a look at that one, that would be fantastic - thank you!