# Resolve a promise in a TypeScript type

Tags: typescript

This is a continuation of [a question about resolving return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53174191/infering-return-type-in-a-nested-object-with-typescript). I'm *so* close to what I'm looking to do (which is to have a common function to build model instances based on validated data) and it works fine in JS, but I can't figure out the final part for the TS typing.

The key is the return for my `Init` type - specifically the `Builder<T[K]>` part. I understand why that results in `Builder<(id: number) => Promise<Test>>` as the returned type, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to tell TS that in fact it is just `Test` being returned, not the function that returns a Promise of `Test`.

The following can be copy / pasted into VSCode (or whatever) to show the issue. The `ter1` variable should be an instance of `Test`, and when compiled to JS it is, but TS doesn't see that.

```
export interface Builder<T> {
    (values: any, db: any): Promise<T>
}

export interface Wrapper {
    <T, TId>(
        construct: (id: TId, db: any | null) => Promise<T>,
        idSrc: string | string[],
        errorMsg: string
    ): Builder<T>
}

let builder: Wrapper = function (construct, idSrc, errorMsg ) {
    // A function that can be used to construct the instance
    return async function(values: any, db: any | null) {
        let id = null;
        let inst = await construct(id, db);

        if (!inst) {
            throw new Error(errorMsg);
        }

        return inst;
    };
}


class Test {
    is1 = true;

    static async fromId( id: number ) {
        var inst = new Test();
        // Some async action (e.g. a db read)
        return inst;
    }
}
class Test2 {
    is2 = true;

    static async fromId( id: number ) {
        var inst = new Test2();
        // Some async action (e.g. a db read)
        return inst;
    }
}


type Config<T extends {}> = {
    inputs?: {[index:string]: any},
    inst?: T;
};

type Init = <T extends {[key:string]: any}>(
    db: any,
    config: Config<T>
) => Promise<{[K in keyof T]: Builder<T[K]>}>; // ???

let init: Init = async function ( db, config ) {
    let ret: any = {};

    if ( config.inst ) {
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(config.inst)) {
            let res = await value( {}, {} );
            ret[ key ] = res;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}


async function allan () {
    let { ter1, ter2 } = await init( null, {
        inst: {
            ter1: Test.fromId,
            ter2: Test2.fromId
        }
    } );

    console.log( ter1.is1, ter1.is2 ); // should be `true undefined`

    // Test `builder` typing
    var t1Wrapper = builder( Test.fromId, 'id', 'test');
    var t2Wrapper = builder( Test2.fromId, 'id', 'test');

    var t1 = await t1Wrapper({}, {});
    var t2 = await t2Wrapper({}, {});

    t1.is1;
    t2.is2;
}

allan();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like the types you want are something like these:

```
type Unpromise<T extends Promise<any>> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : never;

type Init = <T extends { [key: string]: (...args: any[]) => Promise<any> }>(
  db: any,
  config: Config<T>
) => Promise<{ [K in keyof T]: Unpromise<ReturnType<T[K]>> }>;
```

But I haven't spent the time going through all your code to see if it makes sense or if you've implemented it correctly (is this really a [minimum example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?), so please forgive me if you run into some other problem.

Explanation: the way you call `init()` implies that `T` should be an object whose properties are functions that return a promise of the kind you care about.  (I'm not sure if the types and numbers of arguments to those functions are important).  So for each property in `T` you want to extract its return type and then extract the promise type.

- `Unpromise<T>` uses [type inference in conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to pull out  the type of the promised value; so `Unpromise<Promise<XXX>>` should be `XXX`.
- `ReturnType<T>` is a [type from the standard TypeScript library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.1.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1411-L1414) that does a similar thing to get the return type of a function; so `ReturnType<()=>XXX>` should be `XXX`.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Wow! I don't believe I'd ever have got there without your help. `ReturnType` is a new one on me and that is going to be extremely useful. If you have a patreon or anything I'd very much like to buy you a few beers.

Answer (score 4):

TypeScript 4.5 added the `Awaited` type.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#the-awaited-type-and-promise-improvements

```js
// A = string
type A = Awaited<Promise<string>>;
// B = number
type B = Awaited<Promise<Promise<number>>>;
// C = boolean | number
type C = Awaited<boolean | Promise<number>>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The unit type is a function that return a `Promise<{[K in keyof T]: Builder<T[K]>}>`.
Instead it should just return a `Promise<{[K in keyof T]: T[K]}>;`.

Also in the init function you are calling 
`let res = await value( {}, {} );`
But value is the fromId function of Test, that accept only one number parameter.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your reply. I did try `Promise<{[K in keyof T]: T[K]}>` but `T[K]` is the wrapper function that needs to be executed to instantiate a class. Using just `T[K]` as the return means `ter1` is `let ter1: (id: number, db: any) => Promise<Test>` rather than just `Test`. I'm not clear on how to get just the resulting type from that function.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`AsyncReturnType`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest#async) from [`type-fest`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest)!

`type-fest` has something identical to @jcalz's `Unpromise` - it's simply named `PromiseValue` instead.

`AsyncReturnType<FOO>` is basically just `PromiseValue<ReturnType<FOO>>`

So, go ahead:

```
npm install type-fest --save-dev
```

```
yarn add type-fest --dev
```

And use like so:

```
type ServerData = AsyncReturnType<typeof getServerData>
```